# 2 out of 3 axiom and simplicial sets

Tags: reference-request, homotopy-theory, model-categories

Let $i\colon\mathcal W\to\mathcal C$ be the inclusion of a subcategory. Unless I'm mistaken, the 2 out of 3 axiom for $\mathcal W$ to be a category of weak equivalences can be expressed as the existence of the dotted arrow in

[image]

where $\mathrm N$ is the nerve of a category; in other words, $\mathrm N(i)$ is a fibration.

Is this idea used anywhere, maybe in the homotopy theory of model categories?

Comment: That's right. This observation is used to show that the nerve of a category is a Kan complex if and only if it is a groupoid.

Comment: @ZhenLin yes, that's fairly easy to show. I was hoping for... something more. Something like a characterization of model structures on a category by homotopical properties of the relevant subcategories (cofibrations, fibrations, weak equivalences) in the/a model structure on $\mathrm{Cat}$

Comment: There's no reason to expect anything like that. Model structures are surprisingly difficult to construct.